# XCode 7.3 Bug? - Building Project Automatically

Tags: xcode, xcode7

While I'm coding away in XCode, I notice that my project is constantly building and compiling source files and storyboards.

I am not initiating this build at all, as far as I know?

It's getting really annoying. Has anyone else experienced this?

Answer (score 0):

This is a feature. If you don't want it, go to Settings, General and disable "Show Live Issues"